# Sum for unique values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data stored as the tables shows below.

I'm grouping the Order Date by week and I want to show the total Quantity for each unique Order Number (without showing the actual Order Number column in my output).

| Order Date | Week | Order Number | Type | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 | 40 | 123 | A | 2 |
| 2022-10-01 | 40 | 123 | B | 2 |
| 2022-10-01 | 40 | 345 | C | 3 |
| 2022-10-01 | 40 | 345 | A | 3 |
| 2022-10-01 | 40 | 345 | B | 3 |
| 2022-10-01 | 40 | 345 | C | 3 |
| 2022-10-11 | 42 | 456 | B | 1 |
| 2022-10-11 | 42 | 456 | C | 1 |
| 2022-10-12 | 42 | 789 | A | 3 |

I haven't been able to come up with a way to do the sum for Quantity per unique Order Number.

This is my desired ouput :

| Week | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 40 | 5 |
| 42 | 4 |

Comment: Do you just mean count the unique order numbers in each week? If so then just use COUNT(DISTINCT order_number) and GROUP BY week. If that's not what you mean please can you update your question with a more detailed explanation? Also, for future reference, please don't link to images and all all relevant information to your question as editable text (rather than images) - so someone can copy-paste it rather than having to re-type it

Comment: Hi Nick. I want to sum the total Quantity for each week. But only counting the quantity once for each unique Order Number.

Comment: What happens if the same order has different quantities in the same week?

Comment: It shouldn't have different quantities. A colleague asked the same thing when trying to solve it and the solution could be to always pick the first value if for any reason the quantities would not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider below.

```sql
SELECT Week, SUM(Quantity) Quantity FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT Week, Order_Number, Quantity 
    FROM sample_table
) GROUP BY 1;

+------+----------+
| Week | Quantity |
+------+----------+
|   40 |        5 |
|   42 |        4 |
+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH unique_data AS (
    SELECT week, order_number, MAX(quantity) as quantity 
    FROM sample_table
    GROUP BY week, order_number
)
SELECT week, SUM(quantity)
FROM unique_data
GROUP BY week
```